# How can I use javascript to make it so the user can only trigger the hover event once the Lottie animation has played in full?

Tags: javascript, animation, hover, mouseevent, lottie

How can I make it so the user is only able to trigger the mouse hover & mouse left events, once the Lottie animation has initially played in full.

Currently the user is able to cause the hover event when the animation is mid-playing, something I don't want to be able to happen.

Thanks

```
var anim4;
    var anim5 = document.getElementById('lottie5')
    var animation5 = {
        container: anim5,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: false,   /*MAKE SURE THIS IS FALSE*/
        rendererSettings: {
        progressiveLoad: false},
        path: 'https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_H2PpYV.json',
        name: 'myAnimation',
    };
    anim4 = lottie.loadAnimation(animation5);


    // SCROLLING DOWN
    var waypoint5 = new Waypoint({
     element: document.getElementById('lottie5'),
     handler: function(direction) {
       if (direction === 'down') {
         anim4.playSegments([[130,447],[358,447]], true);
         this.destroy()
       }
     },
       offset: '50%'
    })

    anim5.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript1);
    anim5.addEventListener("mouseleave", myScript2);

function myScript1(){
    anim4.goToAndStop(500, true);
}

function myScript2(){
    anim4.playSegments([358,447],true);
};
```

Comment: Maybe you need to have the loop false and add the mouse events when the animation completes. You can use the onComplete event to listen to animation complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out in case anyone is interested.
This might not be the most efficient way, but worked for me!

```
anim4.addEventListener('complete', function(e) { 
    console.log('Animation completed'); 
});

anim4.addEventListener('complete', function(e) {

  var elem = document.getElementById('lottie5');

  elem.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseElem)
  elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseElem2)

  function mouseElem() {
    anim4.goToAndStop(150, true);
  }

  function mouseElem2() {
    anim4.goToAndStop(30, true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var anim4;
    var anim5 = document.getElementById('lottie5')
    var animation5 = {
        container: anim5,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: true,   /*MAKE SURE THIS IS FALSE*/
        rendererSettings: {
        progressiveLoad: false},
        path: 'https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_H2PpYV.json',
        name: 'myAnimation',
    };
    anim4 = lottie.loadAnimation(animation5);


    // SCROLLING DOWN
    var waypoint5 = new Waypoint({
     element: document.getElementById('lottie5'),
     handler: function(direction) {
       if (direction === 'down') {
         anim4.playSegments([[130,447],[358,447]], true);
         this.destroy()
       }
     },
       offset: '50%'
    })

    anim4.addEventListener("complete", function(){
        console.log('Animation completed!!');
        anim5.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript1);
        anim5.addEventListener("mouseleave", myScript2);
    });

function myScript1(){
    anim4.goToAndStop(500, true);
}

function myScript2(){
    anim4.playSegments([358,447],true);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens on hover. What do you think it could be?